# Como incremetar um valor no chart.js com o php

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, chartjs

Estava Trabalhando em um projeto, e tive a ideia de juntar o chart.js com o php, pegar os dados do banco de dados com o php e jogar os valores dentro do script do chart.js para montar um gráfico com base nas informações do banco:

Estava Querendo Fazer algo parecido com esse exemplo:

```
<script>
    var xValues = ["TESTE1", "TESTE2", "TESTE3", "TESTE4", "TESTE5"];
    var yValues = [<?php $valor1 ?>, <?php $valor2 ?>, <?php $valor3 ?>, <?php $valor4 ?>, <?php $valor5 ?>];
    var barColors = ["red", "green","blue","orange","brown"];
    
    new Chart("myChart", {
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        labels: xValues,
        datasets: [{
          backgroundColor: barColors,
          data: yValues
        }]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "World Wide Wine Production"
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Porém passando a tag `<?php $valor ?>` ele não está retornando o grafico, e ficando em branco a pagina.

Alguém tem uma sugestão, ou um jeito mais facil ?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: O arquivo onde você está tentando fazer isso funcionar é .PHP ? Se sim, tente colocar um "echo" antes dos valores: echo $valor1 Se não, acredito que passar os valores através de um JSON seria o ideal.

Comment: Sim é um Arquivo .php, e nesse arquivo também faço uma query , onde armazeno o resultado dela, nessa variavel $valor, fazendo o echo fora da tag script ele aparece.

Answer (score -3):

Nesse caso, para que você consiga mostrar o valor da variável PHP dentro da tag script, é necessário utilizar a função echo (não é bem uma função, mas apenas simplificando).

A forma mais apropriada (e verbosa) para que o resultado esperado seja alcançado é:

```
var yValues = [<?php echo $valor1; ?>, <?php echo $valor2; ?>, <?php echo $valor3; ?>, <?php echo $valor4; ?>, <?php echo $valor5; ?>];
```

Ou ainda, de maneira menos verbosa:

```
var yValues = [<?= $valor1; ?>, <?= $valor2; ?>, <?= $valor3; ?>, <?= $valor4; ?>, <?= $valor5; ?>];
```

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php